# what's the reason for "Current SwiftyJSON (via Swift 3.0.2) cannot be imported with Swift 3.1"

Tags: swifty-json, carthage

When I tried to update *Xcode8.3 (8E162)* today - after updating *carthage* - an error occurred:

> Current SwiftyJSON (via Swift 3.0.2) cannot be imported with Swift 3.1 balabala

and I found out that *SwiftyJSON* did not checkout successful in terminal. Later, after boring me for a few hours, I found that the solution is contained in the official
[GitHub repository issue #771:

"Current SwiftyJSON (via Swift 3.0) cannot be imported with Swift 3.0.2."](https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON/issues/771).

And also with the command

```
:carthage update --no-use-binaries SwiftyJSON --platform iOS
```

you need to remove and add the `SwiftyJSON.framwork` again.

Although this problem is solved, but i do not know the reason, does any buddy know why？

Comment: I improved some major (code) formatting/spelling/highlighting and grammar.

Comment: actually , what i want to ask is : what's the reason for this error occured

Comment: I apologize that I failed to sufficiently reinterpret your question. But if you do know better - because you asked this question - why don't you edit it accordingly?

Comment: Oh no , it's my fault for the first time ask a question on this platform, i have no experience for how to interpret my question concisely , thank you very much.

Comment: I'm sorry if I may have affronted you, but instead of **just editing** your question in the right way (and that is your way!), you chose to continue belittling my efforts to help you.

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure that use run swift 3.1 by type "swift --version" in CLI. If you still see "Apple Swift version 3.0.2" that mean your mac use swift  3.0.2 complier. Try to replace xcode 8.3 to xcode 8.2.1 may help.

Comment: yeah , i think it may workround this error if i restart my Mac when the Xcode updated

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, your question has got me working after spending all day on it - I couldn't figure out where the problem lay.

Now I know what the problem was, it looks like the cause is that SwiftyJSON publish binary versions of their framework, which Carthage downloads and uses. These have not been updated for Swift 3.1 (SwiftyJSON 3.1.4 was released Jan 10), and without the *--no-use-binaries* switch, Carthage will happily use it, even though it is invalid.

Comment: Aha, It sounds very reasonable, perhaps I need to understand the underlying principle of carthage, in order to really avoid such problems in the future